# thermald does not detect any temperature sensors

Tags: linux, intel, temperature, asus, qubes

I have bought a fanless PC, and it is really important for me to have some form of power management for this PC, because currently I don't under Qubes, and the result is that if I do something that puts a lot of load on the CPU like playing a full-screen video in Firefox, the CPU overheats and the system (firmware?) automatically goes into emergency power-saving mode, which involves making the CPU go really slow.

I have transferred responsibility to the Linux kernel for power management by adding `cpufreq=dom0-kernel` to the Xen command line. This doesn't help.

I have then tried to switch from the intel pstate driver (which doesn't work with my Rocket Lake CPU, an Intel® Core™ i7-11700) to the acpi-cpufreq driver by adding `intel_pstate=disable`. This also doesn't help - `sudo cpupower frequency-info` shows "no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU".

I then installed the latest version of `thermald` on my dom0 domain, but `thermald` is not able to find any temperature sensors:

```
[WARN]Thermal DTS: No coretemp sysfs found
```

I have ran `sudo sensors-detect`, but that didn't help.

I have then ran `modprobe processor_thermal_rapl` and `modprobe processor_thermal_device` and restarted `thermald`, but it still showed the same errors.

My motherboard is an Asus TUF GAMING B560M-PLUS WIFI.

Please help me to enable some form of thermal throttling / frequency governor on this PC, other than the firmware's emergency thermal throttling.

Comment: Also tried `acpi=force` and blacklisting xen_acpi_processor, but those didn't help either.

Comment: Are any of the required kernel modules loaded, such as coretemp?

Comment: @Bib When I tried `sudo modprobe coretemp`, I got `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'coretemp': No such device`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's my imagination, but it seems like adding `intel_pstate=disable rdblacklist=xen_acpi_processor` to the kernel command line has solved the original problem, so that I don't need thermald after all.

I'm not sure how that can be the case though, since no driver or process is now controlling the CPU frequency...

**EDIT:** Just to confirm, over a year later, I have had zero overheating events - except one incident where the PC shut down for unknown reasons, which I guess could have been an overheating event. That said, I mostly use this PC for web browsing, so it's not usually very overtaxed.

Comment: Unfortunately my PC is now no longer able to resume from suspend...